# How to write a method to return the string representation of a number in any base not recursive

Tags: java

I wrote the recursive method to change the base but cannot seem to get the interative solution to work. My recursive method looks like this:

```
public static String baseR(int y, int x){
    if (y<x) {
        return new String(""+y);
    } else {
        return new String (baseR(y/x,x)+("" +(y%x))); 
    }
}
```

and my iterative solution looks like this so far:

```
public static String base(int y,int x){
    int remainder = 0;

    while(y!=0){
        y=y/x;
        remainder=y%x;
    }

    return new String(y+(""+ remainder));
}
```

They don't print out the same thing, i have tried a bunch of different ways without  success, does anyone have any pointers?

Comment: Hint: you have a loop, which works out the remainder on each iteration. You're ignoring that remainder. Don't - it's part of the result. (Also, work out the remainder *before* dividing, not after.)

Comment: dguay removed a line when formatting: `new String(y+("" + remainder));`. That line constructed a new `String`, but never assigned it, so it was lost. What did you intend that line to do?

Comment: For the iterative approach, build up the string backwards in the `StringBuilder` by does the remainder and divide you're doing, e.g. `12345` base 10 becomes `54321`, then reverse it by calling [`reverse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse%28%29).

Comment: The end result has to be a string not integer, so i was making a new string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you enter the `while` loop, the value of `remainder` gets overwritten.  You should *"use"* the existing  value of `remainder` before overwriting it.

Also, you should calculate the value of remainder before overwriting the value of `y` with the quotient.

```
public static String base(int y,int x){
    int remainder = 0;
    String value = "";
    while(y!=0){
        remainder=y%x; 
        value= remainder + value; 
        y=y/x;

    }

    return value;
}
```